# how to split a string in powershell based on output from azure command

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I have a powershell script that i'm trying to write.  I need to take some input / output from the console and pipe it into a split command but I don't know how.

I'm running an azure cli command... to list a bunch of resources.  and I need to extract the name of the storage account.
Here's some sample output:

```
Name                  ResourceGroup    Location      Type   
------------------    -------------    ------------  ----------  
asdf1234-insights        jjResourceGrp     eastus    microsoft.insights/components
asdf1234-storage         jjResourceGrp     eastus    Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
asdf1234                 jjResourceGrp     eastus    Microsoft.Web/serverFarms
asdf1234                 jjResourceGrp     eastus    Microsoft.Web/sites
```

This is the powershell command I'm using right now to find just the storage Account:

```
az resource list -g jjResourceGrp -o table | Select-String -Pattern "storageAccounts"
```

But what I really need is to extract the "asdf1234-storage" from that line.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason not to use the corresponding Az PowerShell cmdlets?

Comment: Aw man, I was all excited to help with text parsing! To install the Azure module you can do `Find-Module -Name 'Az' | Install-Module`

Comment: @Ash why you do dis we all wanted to see some `regex` in action :(

Comment: Too late to edit my comment above, but [here is the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageaccount?view=azps-6.0.0) you would need in the Az cmdlets. If you cannot use the Az cmdlets, then why not leave your output as the default i.e. json, and then use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1) to turn your output in to navigable objects? [_grin_] @TeamRegex

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no RegEx needed here. `(az resource list -g jjResourceGrp -o table) -replace '\s+',','|convertfrom-csv|?{$_.type -match 'storageaccounts'}|% Name` does it just fine

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yep, I would've used `\s{2,}` just to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9164015/ash) has pointed out:

- **It is always preferable to use *PowerShell* commands that output *objects whose properties you can operate on***, which in this case requires installing the [`Az`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/6.0.0) PowerShell module (`Install-Module Az`), which then allows you to call [`Get-AzStorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageaccount).
- **If you're interacting with *external programs*, such as the `az` CLI, you're of necessity dealing with *text* (string) output**, which complicates subsequent processing:

  - **The next best option is to deal with an external program's *structured* text output format, if available**, such as CSV or JSON; indeed, as Ash also points out, the `az` CLI's [default output format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli) *is* JSON, so you could omit `-o table` and process the output further with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)
  - Absent that, *text parsing* based, typically based on [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), such as via the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) and [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operators, are required.

---

**To answer the question *as asked*** (because text parsing is so much fun):

The [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement combined with its `-Regex` switch offers a concise solution:

```sh
switch -Regex (az resource list -g jjResourceGrp -o table) {
  '^(\w+).*\bstorageAccounts\b' {
    $Matches[1]; break
  }
}
```