# powershell regex bug

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following code:

```
#look up the app function name for this resource group
switch -Regex (az resource list -g $RESOURCE_NAME -o table) {
    '^(\w+[.-]*\w+).*\bserverFarms\b' {
      $Matches[1]; break
    }
  }
$FUNCTION_APP = $Matches[1]
echo $Matches.Count
echo $Matches[0]
echo $Matches[1]
```

The az resource list command returns the follow output:

```
> az resource list -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -o table
Name                   ResourceGroup    Location    Type                               
----------------------  ---------------  ----------  --------------------------------- 
jf-aa-ext-app-12345      jfFuncs         eastus      microsoft.insights/components
omstorage                jfFuncs         eastus      Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
jf-aa-ext-app-12345      jfFuncs         eastus      Microsoft.Web/serverFarms
jf-aa-ext-app-12345     jfFuncs         eastus      Microsoft.Web/sites
```

Trying to extract "jf-aa-ext-app-12345" from the line that has "serverFarms".
But it's only returning "jf-aa" as a match.

Comment: Does `^(\S*).*\bserverFarms\b` give the results you need?

Comment: In [the question you asked and got that code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812594/how-to-split-a-string-in-powershell-based-on-output-from-azure-command) multiple people recommended using the Azure module to get this info rather than parsing cli output. Why don't you use the module?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician because this code ... ultimately will need to run in a docker container where i may not have the option to  install azure module ... i know it will have the cli...

Comment: I found the regex i need.  '^([\w+.-]*).*\bserverFarms\b'

Comment: I'd recommend outputing as json and then using `ConvertFrom-Json`, or outputing as tsv and using `ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "\`t" -Headers ....`.

Comment: ```az``` has an ```--output json``` option that would be easier to parse with ```ConvertFrom-Json``` - no regex required. From there, you can just ```where-object``` your way to victory...

Comment: @mclayton do you mind if I add your approach in my answer? It is definitely the best one.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try @mclayton

Comment: @mclayton if you want to make an answer, i'll accept.  but please see edit 1

Comment: @santiagosquarzon - sure thing - go for it :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT

Adding this edit at the top because it is clearly the best answer, I was not aware the Azure CLI could output json, thanks [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826684/powershell-regex-bug/67826989#comment119887621_67826684).

```
# Some alternatives using "-o json"

az resource list -g $RESOURCE_NAME -o json | ConvertFrom-Json |
Where-Object {$_.Type -match 'serverFarms'} | Select -Expand Name

# OR

$resGroup = az resource list -g $RESOURCE_NAME -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
$resGroup.where({$_.Type -match 'serverFarms'}).Name
```

---

I propose this solution to your problem, of course, as in yesterday's comments [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812594/how-to-split-a-string-in-powershell-based-on-output-from-azure-command#comment119861815_67812594) recommended using the `Az Module` which is definetly recommended. An alternative to parse this output which will be reusable for future cases, is to convert it to an object which can be easily manipulated (this is what [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812594/how-to-split-a-string-in-powershell-based-on-output-from-azure-command#comment119861962_67812594) proposed which in my opinion is much better than using a particular `regex` to get the result you want).

**Note:** I'm splitting on `'\r\n'` because I'm using a string copy pasted from your question. In your case, simply pipping the result of `az resource...` to `Select-String` should work fine.

```
$output = @'
Name                   ResourceGroup    Location    Type                               
----------------------  ---------------  ----------  --------------------------------- 
jf-aa-ext-app-12345      jfFuncs         eastus      microsoft.insights/components
omstorage                jfFuncs         eastus      Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
jf-aa-ext-app-12345      jfFuncs         eastus      Microsoft.Web/serverFarms
jf-aa-ext-app-12345      jfFuncs         eastus      Microsoft.Web/sites
'@ -split '\r\n' | Select-String -Pattern '^[^-]'

$parsedOutput = $output -replace '\s{2,}',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

#### Output:

```
PS /> $parsedOutput

Name                ResourceGroup Location Type                             
----                ------------- -------- ----                             
jf-aa-ext-app-12345 jfFuncs       eastus   microsoft.insights/components    
omstorage           jfFuncs       eastus   Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
jf-aa-ext-app-12345 jfFuncs       eastus   Microsoft.Web/serverFarms        
jf-aa-ext-app-12345 jfFuncs       eastus   Microsoft.Web/sites              

PS /> $parsedOutput | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name          MemberType   Definition                               
----          ----------   ----------                               
Location      NoteProperty string Location=eastus                   
Name          NoteProperty string Name=jf-aa-ext-app-12345          
ResourceGroup NoteProperty string ResourceGroup=jfFuncs             
Type          NoteProperty string Type=microsoft.insights/components
```

**The result you want:**

```
PS /> $parsedOutput.where({$_.Type -match 'serverFarms'}).Name
jf-aa-ext-app-12345
```

Comment: i appreciate this.  but ultimately, i have to make this work in a dockerized environment where I may not have the option to just install the azure modules.  this is why i've been continuing with the tools i know will be available.  but thank you

Comment: @dot yup, which is why i'm showing you how you can parse the output using what you already have.

Comment: I ended up just using mclaytons suggestion to output in JSON format.  If you can add that here to your answer, i'll accept!  Thank so much though the help!

Comment: @dot done, I added it at the top because it is clearly the best one.